# How to change kernel boot parameters?

Tags: kernel, cpu, cpufreq

I need to turn CPUIDLE Off on Ubunto 20.04
The instructions I have are:

"Disable CPUIDLE via the kernel command-line in grub:"

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4-19.0-16-rt-amd64 cpuidle.off=1
```

How do I do this in my distro ? I also need to make some other changes but they are all similar.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add there `cpuidle.off=1` like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash cpuidle.off=1"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`